# Home page on my project sometimes wont fit the screen width

Tags: html, css, project, codeanywhere

Has anyone ever had this issue? In the left picture using git hub pages (this also happens in dev tools) the home page won't fill the screen, this happens about 60% of the time, the other 40% is fine. But if I go to the galley or form page, and then go back to my home page it works fine every time (picture right ). I have cached every time I add a new CSS element, I have to hand in my HTML and CSS project on the 20th of this month so need to figure out the issue, TIA [First log on wont fit screen ][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRLOj.png)
[This is the correct width after I return back to the home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzeRN.jpg)

I cleared the cache everytime I made a change to my project and I also cached Dev Tools, I have my html and CSS valadied

Comment: Hi Danny, it's unclear to me what issue you're running in to. Both screenshots look identical to me. Also, is it possible to publish the github page so we can take a look at the code?

Comment: https://danij1990.github.io/mullingar-hiking/     I posted the same image twice by mistake, I have changed it ! I’ve sent the link to a few people and they haven’t ran in to the issue but it keeps happing to me it’s so weird

Comment: Thanks. I'm able to consistently reproduce this on desktop with Chrome developer tools (render as mobile). Not sure what is going wrong but the paddings on `.about-us` and `.words` are rendering incorrectly.

Comment: what do you mean it "sometimes" doesn't work? when does it work, and when does it not work exactly? if there is a CSS problem, the issue should be present at all times.

Comment: That’s exactly what I mean, sometimes the page loads perfect, I could leave the page and open it again 20 minutes later and it opens incorrectly as showed in the pictures